# Android Will the CountDownTimer remain counting when device goes to sleep?

Tags: android

I am using a CountDownTimer to log a user out of my app after a specified time. I am wondering if the Timer keeps going even if my app is sent to the background or if the phone locks because the user put their phone down? If anyone thinks I should use a different timer method please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CountDownTimer wll not work when the phone goes to sleep:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/973bcb3bb806d13?pli=1

When I stopped using wakelock, the CountDownTimer never finished. Works with wakelock though.

Comment: Yea I found this to be the case, ended up just using my own thread to do the managing rather than built in Android stuff. With a WakeLock of course. Thanks.

Comment: You can use java.util.Timer for timing instead, it works fine without a WakeLock, so you can save quite a bit of battery that way (unless of course you need the WakeLock for other things).

Comment: Looks like java.util.Timer can pause for 6 minutes when the phone is in deep sleep. So it's not very reliable.

Comment: The real solution is to use android.app.AlarmManager when your service needs to run without a wakelock.